# How to remove KDE Connect dependecies in Cinnamon or any other DE?

Tags: uninstall, cinnamon, purge, kde-apps, kde-connect

I installed KDE Connect in Ubuntu 14.04 with Unity. Now I want to remove the app and all 60 MB of KDE dependencies. If I don't know those package names, how can I remove all the dependencies and not just the app KDE Connect?

Comment: Mint questions are off topic here. However you should be able to remove most of the installed files by entering into the terminal `sudo apt-get purge kdeconnect`  to remove kde connect then enter `sudo apt-get autoremove` to remove any packages that are no longer required.  This may leave some files on your system but should remove most of them.

Comment: Note on off topic.  Your title asks for "any other DE"  while this may seem on-topic it is most likely still not.  If you were using Ubuntu with Cinnamon installed it would be on topic.  However as you are using Mint as a base system the off topic issue comes up.  While Mint is based on Ubuntu there may be subtle changes that could make the answer different for each Distro.  While most answers would still work, the community here would not want to take responsibility upon ourselves by giving you an answer that could break your system.

Comment: @TrailRider thank you for your answer. I edited the question so it is on topic now. I read here [link](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/11/kde-connect-indicator-use-kde-connect.html) that 'apt-get autoremove' doesn't help. That is why I am asking this.

Comment: The link you provided has [another link](http://pastebin.com/aKvMtEgR), which lists all of the dependencies.

Comment: @TSJNachos117 yes it has, but I don't know what to do with that list 'sudo apt-get remove _ThatList_' or something else? I want to learn generaly how to remove dependencies not just for this app.

Comment: While technically a Mint question would be off-topic, the answer is the same for any Debian-based distro. Otoh, it has zero to do with kde-connect, kde-apps, or even Cinnamon...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I understand that you are asking about "kdeconnect" removal process.
First check whether you have KDE packages installed by typing:

```
dpkg -l | grep kdeconnect
```

if it shows something like this

```
ii  kdeconnect 0.8-0ubuntu5 
    amd64                   connect smartphones to your KDE Plasma Workspace  
ii  kdeconnect-plasma 0.9+git20160315-0ubuntu1 
    amd64                   connect smartphones to your KDE Plasma desktop
```

then you are good to go.

First kill the running KDE Connect processes:

```
killall kdeconnectd
```

Type the following command to uninstall KDE Connect:

```
sudo apt-get remove kdeconnect
```

This will just remove KDE Connect.
For removing its dependencies type this:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

That should remove all the dependencies needed for KDE and you will have no KDE Connect, no KDE indicator nor KDE monitor, which is present in the Unity launcher.

I hope that this helps. It worked for me.

Comment: dpkg -l | grep kdeconnect
`rc  kdeconnect    1.3.3-0ubuntu0.18.04.1     amd64   connect smartphones to your KDE Plasma Workspace`


 sudo apt-get remove kdeconnect:
`Package 'kdeconnect' is not installed, so not removed`

Comment: To remove the `rc` status in the output of `dpkg -l` use: `dpkg --purge kdeconnect`. This will remove the configuration files created by `kdeconnect`.